# ImportError: cannot import name Connection while adding session?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, session

I have a django project working fine . now i need to add login with session on that project I use [mango](https://github.com/vpulim/mango) .

As added in setting.py file

```
 SESSION_ENGINE = 'mango.session'
```

then it started to give following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 52, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 11, in __init__
    engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/shubham/Music/ekomerz/mango/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pymongo import Connection
ImportError: cannot import name Connection
```

how I can solve this ?

and is there is any other method should i try for login with session ?

Comment: there is not `Connection` in latest `pymango` (https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html). Please check with `mango`, which version they used? I checked `mango` docs (https://github.com/vpulim/mango) but they not mention `pymango` version. They might be not updated after new version

Comment: should i have to change Connection to MongoClient

Comment: Dont change in third party library, if they have IRC or MAIL, please drop mail to them and check, which version they were using?

Comment: Thanks Lafada for your time .  I solve this changing Connection to MongoClient